# Max sum in the vector, according to the condition, which is defined by another vector

Tags: algorithm

I have `2` variables in the data.frame: `a, b`.
I need to find the max sum of `a`, where `sum of b = x`.

Ok, for example:

```
| a | b |
|401| 2 |
|380| 3 |
|380| 2 |
|370| 1 |
```

So, for `sum(b)=1`, `max(sum(a)) = 370`, for `sum(b)=2`, `max(sum(a))=401` etc.
How can I find a solution to this problem?

Not sure that this problem can be solved using linear programming

Comment: Can you please try to givemore explain? Maybe and example? And it is expected from you to try solve it first by your own so please share what you have tried!

Comment: Just to satisfy the `sum b = x` condition, you'd need to solve a [subset sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) problem, which is known to be NP-complete. Are there any restrictions on `b`?

Comment: @user58697 `b` can only be 1, 2 or 3 (in this dataset)

Comment: For `sum(b)=3` it should be `401+370` right?

Comment: Need some more examples for understanding the problem. Where is the `sum` of anything here? What's the meaning of `sum(b)`?

Comment: I’m thinking dynamic programming (not my home field, so no guarantees).

Comment: This seems very close to the knapsack problem, the only difference being that you're specifying the *exact* total weight instead of an *upper bound* on the total weight.

Comment: @ruakh yeah! This is what I was looking for (I mean knapsack problem), thank u!